# Adding div to WordPress page content

Tags: posts, html, content

I am wondering if there is a way to add `div` to specific elements in the WordPress page content?

For example, I would want to wrap a div around content starting at a H2 element and ending after an `img` element. The `div` should have custom classes assigned to them.

Is there anyway to do this? I don't want to have to hard-code the `div` so that other people can easily edit the page content.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used JQuery to fix this problem and target the specific elements.

In particular, I used: wrap, wrapInner, wrapAll, replaceWith, unWrap, and remove.